# Firewall on existing building

Tags: walls, exterior

We are required to create a firewall on our building that is less than 5' from the property line. We removed a window and now need to know if we can just leave the old header and framing and insert studs at 16" centers within the old window opening. Can anyone offer insight into this?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, that is common practice. Not much insight required, sounds like you got this.

Comment: Thank you, I was just concerned they might cause a stink but this is good news

Comment: +1; but just make sure the wood is solid. So often it isn't!

Answer (score 0):

Setbacks from property lines are based on the buildings "occupancy", (i.e.: residential, commercial, institutional, etc.) (IBC Table 601) AND what it is made out of, (i.e.: concrete, wood, etc.) (IBC Table 602.) When a building of a certain occupancy encroaches into this required setback, the exterior wall must be constructed a certain way...we call this a "firewall".

There are many kinds of "fire walls" and they are constructed in many ways. Most need to "protect" openings (i.e.: windows, doors, vents, electrical outlet boxes, etc.) based on the setback and type of construction. In addition, most firewalls need to extend a minimum of 30" above the roof...although that can be eliminated by installing gypsum board on top of the roof sheathing and on the bottom of the roof structure, (i.e.: roof trusses, roof joists, etc.)

You say your "Building" is within 5' of the property line. (You didn't say residence.) So, in order to answer your question about framing, I really need to know the type of occupancy.

In any event, just removing windows and infilling with framing, siding, etc. is NOT acceptable for ANY type of firewall. In wood frame construction, the minimum requirement for a firewall is one layer of gypsum board is required on the exterior (under the siding) and one layer of Type-X gypsum board is required on the inside.

I would check with your local Building Official to get a clarification of the type of firewall required and exactly how it should be constructed. All firewalls are designed and tested to meet U.L. Standards (or Warnock Hersey Standards) AND they must be constructed to match those specifications, (i.e.: thickness of material, nailing patterns, framing dimensions, framing spacing, etc.)

(Btw, you know there is no firewall required on the "front" of your building. Firewalls are for the sides and rear of buildings ONLY.)

Comment: This is a detached garage being converted into a business. The wall in question is a side wall close to the property line. We are aware of the fire wall requirements but specifically I had questions regarding the framing - we removed a window and I wanted to know if they were particular about how that was handled. i.e. - would we have to remove existing framing from window or could we just insert studs within the existing opening and then proceed with the required fire proofing .. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you can "infill" an opening with framing that matches the "fire rating" of the rest of the wall, (i.e.: same size and spacing of other framing members).